# Set Chrome Custom Tabs as the Main View

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

I am trying to create an application that loads a webpage on launch. Previously, I have used a `WebView` to do this, but this lacks performance, speed, cookies, etc. With the recent update, `CustomTabs` has been introduced, bringing huge improvements and features of the Chrome browser.

However, `CustomTabs` only seems to work as a full-screen dialog, which means if the user closes the tab, they will go back to the main view. Is there a way to use `CustomTabs` as an independent view, or make it the MainActivity itself?

P.S. How would you remove the <kbd>x</kbd> button in `CustomTabs`?

Comment: "How would you use Chrome Custom Tabs as the initial view of the Activity" -- AFAIK, Chrome custom tabs are a separate activity, not a view that you embed in your own activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you launch this activity directly?

Comment: Well, the user can launch Chrome directly. AFAIK, you can't have an `<activity>` element that goes straight to a Chrome custom tab, as that connection needs to be set up in Java.

Comment: @CommonsWare then, is there a way to remove the X button?

Comment: I do not know, sorry.

Comment: you can customize how the x button looks

Comment: @EgorPasko I would rather have it removed :(

Answer (score 0):

Things you can do with Chrome:

1. "Add to Homescreen": https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen
2. have an Android app that sends an intent with the URL of your website to regular Chrome (fullscreen cannot be enabled without user action though, see: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/fullscreen/)

Comment: I do not control the source of the website I am displaying. So these methods cannot be  used.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the Custom Tab inside the `onCreate()` method from your Activity and call `finish()` right after opening the tab.

One of the [demos](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/demos/src/main/java/org/chromium/customtabsdemos/NotificationParentActivity.java) on GitHub does something similar: The Notification starts one of the Activity inside the demo, which starts the Custom Tab. When the user clicks on the "x", she's taken back to the original Activity.

It is not possible to remove the Close Button. You could use a transparent icon on the button, but the click target will still exist and if the user clicks that area, the tab will be closed.

If you are using this to open 3rd party content, be careful to show the user that she is opening it inside your application to avoid being seen as an [impersonator](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2986097?hl=en-GB), which is agains the Google Play policy.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing right now. But the X button really bugs me :( So I just decided to add content to the MainActivity so it looks more natural.